# How to call this method from a separate main java file?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I need to call the sortRows method in the main method from a separate java file. How do I split this up so that the the testing is done within the sortRows method and the calling is done in the main method? The codes below are the same, but no matter the way I split them up, I would get an error.

Main Method:

```
    Chapter8.chap8method();
    final int SIZE = 3;
    double[][] m = new double[SIZE][SIZE];
    double[] i1 = new double[] {0.15, 0.875, 0.375};
    System.out.print("1st array : ");
    Arrays.sort(i1);
    for(int index=0; index < i1.length ; index++)
    System.out.print("  " + i1[index]);


    double[] i2 = new double[]{0.55, 0.005,0.225};
    Arrays.sort(i2);
    System.out.print('\n' + "2nd array : ");
    for(int index=0; index < i2.length ; index++)
        System.out.print("  " + i2[index]);


    double[] i3 = new double[]{0.30, 0.12, 0.4};
    Arrays.sort(i3);
    System.out.print('\n' + "3nd array : ");
    for(int index=0; index < i3.length ; index++)
      System.out.print("  "  + i3[index]);

    ------------------------------------------------------
```

sortRows Method

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    public class Chapter8 {
    public static void chap8method(){
    }

public static double[][] sortRows(double[][] m) {
    double[][] result = new double[m.length][m[0].length];
        //create an int array
        double[] i1 = new double[] {0.15, 0.875, 0.375};
        System.out.print("1st array : ");
        Arrays.sort(i1);
        for(int index=0; index < i1.length ; index++);



        double[] i2 = new double[]{0.55, 0.005,0.225};
        Arrays.sort(i2);
        System.out.print('\n' + "2nd array : ");
        for(int index=0; index < i2.length ; index++)
            System.out.print("  " + i2[index]);


        double[] i3 = new double[]{0.30, 0.12, 0.4};
        Arrays.sort(i3);
        System.out.print('\n' + "3nd array : ");
        for(int index=0; index < i3.length ; index++)
          System.out.print("  "  + i3[index]);

        return result;
      }
      }
```

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do. What does: *The codes below are the same, but no matter the way I split them up, I would get an error.* mean?

Comment: the method `sortRows(m:double[][]):double[][]` must be inside a class, then call it as `Target_Clazz.sortRows(...)`

Comment: I need to rearrange them in a way where i would be outputting from the main method. Not from the sortrows. No printing should be in the sortrows, but when i rearrange it to do that, would get errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
package test;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Snippet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int SIZE = 3;
        double[][] m = new double[SIZE][SIZE];
        m[0] = new double[] {0.95, 0.875, 0.375};
        m[1] = new double[]{0.55, 0.005,0.225};
        m[2] = new double[]{0.30, 0.12, 0.4};
        for(int i=0;i<m.length;i++){
             for(int index=0; index < m[i].length ; index++){
                 System.out.print("  " + m[i][index]);
             }
             System.out.println();
        }

        double[][] result = SortRow.sortRows(m);
        System.out.println("After sorted:");

        for(int i=0;i<result.length;i++){
            for(int index=0; index < result[i].length ; index++){
                 System.out.print("  " + result[i][index]);
             }
             System.out.println();
        }
    }

}

class SortRow {
    public static double[][] sortRows(double[][] m) {
        double[][] result = new double[m.length][m[0].length];
        for(int i=0;i<m.length;i++){
            Arrays.sort(m[i]);
            result[i] = m[i];
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to be able to call a method and output information outside of that.

to avoid doing the assignment for you I'll provide an example I think will help.

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String taskValue = MyClass.workHard("first task");
    System.out.println(taskValue);

    taskValue = MyClass.workHard("second task")
    System.out.println(taskValue);   

    taskValue = MyClass.workHard("third task")
    System.out.println(taskValue);

    taskValue = MyCLass.workWard("fourth task");
    System.out.println(taskValue);
  }  
}


public class MyClass {
  public static String workHard(String message){
    //do a bunch of operations ...
    System.out.println("Finished work for " + taskMessage);
    return "Ending"
  }
}
```

this would print 
Finished work for first task
Ending first task
Finished work for second task
Ending second task
Finished work for third task
Ending third task
Finished work for fourth task
Ending fourth task